# pageTest C# wrapper

Tags: c#, wrapper

I would like to obtain the results retrieved from pageTest execution (core @ [CVS](http://pagetest.cvs.sourceforge.net/pagetest/pagetest/)) from a C# project (library or console). pageTest source code shows a dynamic library project (generating a DLL file) and also an application project (generating an EXE file).

Do anybody have previous experience related to this issue? Any tips or recommendations?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at [PINVOKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) for more information I think. The Link is to an MSDN article called : Calling Win32 DLLs in C# with P/Invoke